# Removing characters from a character string without any libraries

Tags: c

I need to remove a specified number of characters from a character string without any libraries.

This function should take three arguments: the string, the starting index number and the number of characters to remove.
And I haven't learnt pointers yet so I can't use them.

I've written this code, and it works for my single test case. Are there any errors I've missed, or improvements, or better ways to approach the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removeString(char string[], int index, int number)
{
    int i, j;
    index--;

    for (i = index, j = index + number; string[j] != '\0'; i++, j++)
    {
        string[i] = string[j];
    }

    string[i] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "this";

    removeString(string, 2, 2);

    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

Comment: "need to remove a specified number from a character string" - that's quite vague...

Comment: @headbanger Homework is ok as long as he tried something and asked a specific question.

Comment: Your code is okay if it does the job. And if it does not, then it is not okay.

Comment: JFYI: "*I haven't learned pointers yet so I can't use them*", you already are. `char string[]` turns into `char *string`, a pointer.

Comment: What if `index` or `number` is not between 0 and 4(in your case)?

Comment: The first question is: does it compile? It looks like is should. Next: does it do what you want on the single sample data?  It looks like it might.  Then you need to devise a scheme to test it more thoroughly — how could you devise ways to break the code.  You'll need sample inputs and for each input, the expected output.  Since your code only uses what you wrote plus I/O functions, it meets the 'standard I/O only' criterion.

Comment: What does the `stdio` library have to do with string manipulation?

Comment: @ScottHunter: The standard I/O functions have nothing to do with string manipulation — but it means he isn't allowed to use the functions from `<string.h>` or `<ctype.h>`, etc.

Comment: This is exercise 10.6 from programming in c by Stephen Kochan. Should I write all details in this exercise?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - That's some superb telepathy :)

Comment: @luqua: No; but you might well mention the exercise in an update to the question.

Comment: @Useless: when you've seen enough questions, you realize what people mean with some of the restrictions placed on their solutions.  You can end up with some very weird restrictions, and consequently very weird answers, as a result of more or less arbitrary conditions placed on the questioner by some outside authority (usually a teacher, sometimes a text book).

Comment: I added additional condition. Sorry for my inconvenient. I'm a beginner in programming and asking questions.

Comment: Don't worry about that, it was a minor confusion. I've showed a couple of problems with your existing code, and ways to fix them.

Answer (score 4):

`stdio` is short for Standard Input/Output. If you're not doing input, or output, you're not using this library.

The only way I can see to use stdio to do this, is to control *what you output*, that is, printing one character at a time if they're not supposed to be removed. That doesn't change the string in place, at all.

---

Conversely, if you just need to implement your `removeString` method *without* using any other libraries (not necessarily using stdio), let's start by looking at your existing code:

```
void removeString(char string[], int index, int number)
{
    int i, j;
    index--;

    for (i = index, ...)
```

what happens here if `index==0`? It seems like that should be a valid input, but you start with `i=-1`. Well, that *could* be ok, so long as we don't use it as in index

```
            string[i] = ...
```

oh dear, we just wrote before the start of our array. We need to be more careful about that.
How about `j`?

```
    for(..., j = index + number; string[j] != '\0'; i++, j++)
    {
        string[i] = string[j];
```

well, this is bad if `index+number` is greater than the length of our string - we *start* by reading past the end of our array.

A safe version might look like this:

```
void removeString(char string[], int index, int number)
{
    int i, j;

    /* make sure inputs are sane */
    if (index < 0) index = 0;
    if (number < 1) number = 1;
    /* make sure index < strlen(string) without using strlen */
    for (i = 0; i<index; i++) {
        if (string[i] == '\0') return;
    }
    /* advance j, stopping if we hit the end */
    for (j = i+1; j < i+number && string[j]; j++) {}
    /* now copy from i to j, stopping at the end */
    do {
        string[i++] = string[j];
    } while (string[j++]);
}
```

which has the following invariants:

- `index` is not allowed to be less than zero
- `number` is not allowed to be less than one (could make this zero as for index?)
- if `index` is greater than the total length of the string, nothing is changed
- if `index+number` is greater than the total length of the string, we truncate the string at `index`

a useful way to think about the structure, is that our function divides the string into three parts, and we have a loop for each part:

1. before the removed section (`0 <= i <= index`) is the first loop
2. inside the removed section (`index < j < index+number`) is the second
3. after the removed section (`index <= i && index+number <= j <= end`) is the third

---

Since you're a beginner, it's worth noting that all three of those loops are somewhat carefully written. That is to say, it takes care to get them right, and it might be easier (and perhaps better style) to use more regular forms. Particularly, the `do/while` loop has two post increment expressions which have to be in the right place, which is a little brittle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void removeString(char string[], int index)
{
   int i = index - 1;
   for(; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
    string[i] = string[i+1];
   }
}

int main(void)
{
   char string[] = "this";
   removeString(string, 2);
   printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

*mistake in your code*

- You will actually just get `ts` with your code, because all your `for loop` in `removeString` method does is a single assignment at position 1 with the value at position 3 of the character array.

**EDIT**

You said you don't know pointers but you are actually using the concept of pointers in the program. How do you think that a `void function` is able to make changes to your `string`, It is because in your `removeString` function you are actually sending base address of the array and changes made to that memory location persist and your `printf` statement is reference to same location which underwent changes in you previous statement. That the magic of pointers.

Comment: The code given in the question produces `ts`. You've overlooked the assignment of a null to terminate the string after the loop that is present in the code in the question and missing from your code.  Your code also does a different operation from the code in the question; it eliminates one character, not 2 characters.  Note that if you called your function with the value 0 for the `index` parameter, it runs into undefined behaviour (though so does the code in the question).